# Contador de visitas solo cada 60 segundos con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy creando un contador de visitar simple, pero quiero que solo incremente el contador de visitas si el usuario ha refrescado la pagina tras 60 segundos

Tengo lo siguiente:

```php
namespace Codelaby\EventDateGenerator;

class CounterVisitors
{
    private String $filename  = "counter.txt";

    private function saveCounter($counter = 0)
    {

        if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
            touch($this->filename);
        }

        $fp = fopen($this->filename, "w");

        while (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) { 
            return;
        }
        fwrite($fp, $counter);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
    }

    public function readCounter()
    {
        if (!file_exists($this->filename)) {
            touch($this->filename);
        }
        $fp = fopen($this->filename, "r");
        if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
            return;
        }
        $file_size = filesize($this->filename);
        if ($file_size <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        $counter = intval(fread($fp, $file_size));
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fp);
        return $counter;
    }


    public function hitCounter()
    {
        $counter = $this->readCounter();
        $counter++;
        $this->saveCounter($counter);
        return $counter;
    }

    public function resetCounter($counter = 0)
    {
        $this->saveCounter(0);
    }
}
```

Su uso

```php
use Codelaby\EventDateGenerator\CounterVisitors;

$counterVisitors = new CounterVisitors();
$visitors = $counterVisitors->hitCounter();
echo "visitas: " . $visitors;
```

Ahora me incrementa el contador cada vez que el usuario le dar refrescar

Como se podría evitar que si refresca entre los 60 segundos de su primera visita no incremente el contador?

Comment: ninguna de las opciones que indicas es correcta; lo adecuado seria llevar un control de lo que a visitado el usuario, y si visista por segunda vez el mismo lugar que no cuente... eso deberia estar en algun lugar de tu estructura ...

Answer (score 1):

Una forma puede ser generar una variable de session que contenga un timestamp y contrastarla con el nuevo timestamp. Si el usuario está navegando, el tiempo no debería seguirse sumando, por lo que la reiniciarías con el timestamp actual, para que no cuente luego de 60 segundos una nueva visita de alguien que está navegando.
Sólo sería una nueva visita luego de una inactividad de 60 segundos.
Algo así:

```
@session_start(); //al inicio del fichero

//---

if($_SESSION['initial_access_time']) {
    
        if($_SESSION['initial_access_time'] < (time() - 60)) {

            $_SESSION['initial_access_time'] = time();

            use Codelaby\EventDateGenerator\CounterVisitors;

            $counterVisitors = new CounterVisitors();
            $visitors = $counterVisitors->hitCounter();
            echo "visitas: " . $visitors;               

        } else {
    
            $_SESSION['initial_access_time'] = time();

        }

} else {
    
    $_SESSION['initial_access_time'] = time();

}
```

Espero sirva!